# How do I get echo these values out of this array?

Tags: php, html

How would I be able to echo the values out of this array?

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["task_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["task_title"]=>
    string(15) "The Second Task"
    ["task_description"]=>
    string(41) "Pretty much the same as the first task..."
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["task_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["task_title"]=>
    string(9) "Test Task"
    ["task_description"]=>
    string(35) "This is a description for the task."
  }
}
```

Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

Comment: For testing purposes? `print_r()`... Otherwise: could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: You can use [foreach construct](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$array=array(
    array(
    "task_id"=> "2",
    "task_title"=>"The Second Task",
    "task_description"=> "Pretty much the same as the first task..."
  ),
  array( 
    "task_id"=>"1",
    "task_title"=>"Test Task",
    "task_description"=>"This is a description for the task."
  )
);
echo $array[0]['task_id'];
```

or try this

```
  foreach($array as $key=>$value){
      foreach($value as $k=>$v){
           echo $v . "<br/>";
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work to print your values!

```
<?php

  foreach ($array as $innerArray)
    foreach ($innerArray as $value)
        echo $value;

?>
```